# Getting repeating loop infinit

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, nested-loops

I am using nested for loop for getting from arraylist  and  that loop run infinte

private ArrayList prepareData()
    {

```
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<android_image_urls.length;i++){

            Androidversionclass androidversion = new Androidversionclass();
            androidversion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
            arrayList.add(androidversion);

                for (int k= 0; k < android_image_second.length; k++) {
                    Androidversionclass androidversionclass1 = new Androidversionclass();
                    androidversion.setAndroid_image_second(android_image_second[k]);
                    arrayList.add(androidversion);
                }

                for (int l = 0; l < android_image_thirds.length; l++) {
                    Androidversionclass androidversionclass2 = new Androidversionclass();
                    androidversion.setAndroid_image_thirds(android_image_thirds[l]);
                    arrayList.add(androidversion);

                }

                for (int m = 0; m < android_image_fourth.length; m++) {
                    Androidversionclass androidversionclass3 = new Androidversionclass();
                    androidversion.setAndroid_image_fourth(android_image_fourth[m]);
                    arrayList.add(androidversion);
            }
        }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain which loop you think is not ending. Also, is it possible you are inadvertently extending one of the inner array variables each pass through the outer loop?

Comment: @tbm sir  i didnt get you please ellaborate so i can resolve my problem

Comment: you say " that loop run infinte" - there are four loops in your code, which one is running infinitely?